# Vertically stretch div 100% height

Tags: css, html

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jf5J8/1/)

How to make 2nd div streatch to all its vertical place. It has to 'take care' of bottom margin of div above him and bottom margin of all the page. How to make it fill all that place? There will be normal content inside it, I will make page that will be scrolling horizontally and I need it to fit in various user Y resolutions. Bottom margin will be constant. I would really like to avoid js in that.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.com) which illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just that: no matter if Y screen size of user is 1080 or 768 or whatever website will have constant top and bottom margin, some header of website and left vertical place need to be filled by some long, horizontal div that will have all the content inside.

Comment: I think your only solution is with JS; you can get the window height, and dynamically adjust the height of the div based on that value. Is there a particular reason you're avoiding JS?

Comment: So it is impossible with css? Its accidentally the same thing as width:100%. I dont get it. If I had no choice, I will use JS, but I would love to do it with css, especially when it will be responsive layout - a lot of things to care.

Comment: @Alfo Thanks for the correction. I really need to just copy and paste that instead of typing it out each time. (And double-check my links when I make them...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jf5J8/2/

```
#rest {
         background-color:blue;
         height:100%;
         position:relative;
         top:0;left:0;
         bottom:0;right:0;
      }
html, body {
             height:100%;
           }
```

Your code

```
#rest {
    background-color:blue;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:auto;
```

}

contains two time `height`. Remove `height:auto;` in the end

Comment: page is scrolling, div is just as high as all the window, it dont fit to only free space that has left 'not taken'

Comment: 1. Page will scroll only horizontally, so it cant be more tall than document. 2.For example, we got 800px high document, top and bottom margins have 50px, so 700px left on page. Header has lets say 80px height so 620px has left. So our div has to be 620px high to take all left place. Of course it shold fit on every monitor, every resolution, should react to window resize, and would be great to do it with css